# How send mail in laravel and RollbarNotifier

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, rollbar

I develop a laravel app and I want to automatically send emails with remainder to users.

I created command like in this [article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-send-email-with-laravel-commands). But I get this error:

```
  [Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]
  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $config ]] in
  class RollbarNotifier
```

This is my code:

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=example.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=PAssWord
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="FROM FROM"

ROLLBAR_TOKEN=<my_token>
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'example.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'noreply@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'FROM FROM'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'SSL'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],    
];
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @MarkWalet I use laravel 5.5.42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dependency injection is not working. It is missing a configuration file.

I am not sure which package you are using. But when I look at the installation manual at https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-rollbar I see you also have to add some configuration in the `services.php`:

```
'rollbar' => [
    'access_token' => env('ROLLBAR_TOKEN'),
    'level' => env('ROLLBAR_LEVEL'),
],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had same more errors with mail config but your solution help with above problem. Regards